# Zigbee simulation in OMNeT++ using INET 3.0 (without MiXiM)

Tags: module, simulation, omnet++, zigbee, inet

I am trying to build a Zigbee (802.15.4) network simulation in OMNeT++ using INET 3.0 framework (MiXiM was deprecated and replaced by this version ).
The problem is that unlike 802.11, the Zigbee is not fully standardize by its Alliance, so the modules in the framework are not complete nor ready for use.

I searched for an example that uses Zigbee all over the web but found none that uses INET 3.0, I found some that uses the old MiXiM. The INET 3.0 was released a few months ago.

I also tried to build my own Zigbee node but was not very lucky.

Can anyone please guide me to an example of Zigbee simulation in OMNeT++ under the INET 3.0 framework, or at least a node structure?

I forgot to mention that I am a novice to OMNeT++ and to INET.

Answer (score 0):

Within an updated inet 3.x append in the file `inet/examples/wireless/nic/omnetpp.ini` the following config section:

```
[Config IEEE802154]
network = TestNic
extends = AbstractAPSKScalarRadio
*.host[*].wlan[*].typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandNic"
```

The configured simulation represents a simple narrow-band CSMA/CA based IEEE 802.15.4 network which is related to ZigBee networks.

Then you have to run the configured simulation:

1. Right-click on the edited `omnetpp.ini`
2. Select `Run as`, then `OMNeT++ Simulation`
3. Change to new config `IEEE802154`
4. Finally, press `ok`